# Overflow-y causes the div to have height of zero

Tags: html, css, firefox, bootstrap-4

I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #left {
        position: absolute;
        top: 52px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 25%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: calc(100% - 62px);
    }

    #right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 52px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 75%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: calc(100% - 62px);
    }
}
```

When I inspect the DOM, the height of the content classes is as expected, but the left and right divs have zero height and thus nothing shows on the page.

Removing the overflow-y property fixes the problem but I do need scrolling in case the div exceeds the height of the screen.

I tried the "clearfix" wrapper around the left and right divs but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Could someone explain why is the parent class not inheriting the height of its content?

This is only an issue in Firefox by the way, Chrome seems to work fine.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me in firefox. content shows up and is scrollable. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/dRpwwG

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to not come from the `overflow-y`, but rather that you have missed out the closing quotation mark in `<div class="row">`. Failure to include this closing quotation mark actually causes the `<div>` on the left to not display. My guess is that Chrome automatically corrects this, and Firefox does not.

I've added in some background colours, and created a JSFiddle showcasing this problem [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9m9aLmf9/), and another fixing this problem [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/kay543e2/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately that's just a typo - I simplified the code for the sake of the example.

Comment: Darn haha. Although my fiddle is displaying correctly for me in both Firefox and Chrome. Could you please confirm that your code isn't working, and ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the problem? I remember IE having an issue with percentage-based heights when the parent doesn't **explicitly specify a height**, so it's possible you're having a similar issue. Maybe try specifying a height on your `.row`.

Comment: Specifying the height of the row does work, the problem is that I don't want to hardcode that. Using percentages doesn't work.

Comment: Using percentages should work, as long as you keep using relative percentages **up to** a final fixed height. Don't forget that it can also be on body, which you should be able to specify `100vh` on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a height setting containing percentage values for an element (as you did), the *parent* of that element needs a `height`setting too. If you mean 100% - 62px of the window height, you have to add `height: 100%` to each parent, grandparent etc. - a percentag-based settong needs a reference in the parent element. In you case that would be

```
html, body, .row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html,
  body,
  .row {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 62px);
  }
  #right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 62px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```